# Unable to access a field's value via javascript function on aspx page on passing client id from function call in code behind(page load)

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a javascript function as follows

```
function textCounter(field, rem, maxlimit) {
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
            field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        else
            rem.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
```

I am trying to call it from code behind by passing clien ID's

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "textCounter('" + txtRemark.ClientID + "','" + txtRemarksRem.ClientID + "', '2000')", true);
```

But I am unable to get the values of the associated fields.
I am getting null value for "field.value.length"

Let me know the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing only client Ids for the controls, but not the control, you should first get those control to work.

for that you should change your code as

```
function textCounter(field, rem, maxlimit) {

    var fieldCtrl = document.getElementById(field);
    var remCtrl = document.getElementById(rem);

    if (fieldCtrl.value.length > maxlimit)
        fieldCtrl.value = fieldCtrl.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    else
        remCtrl.value = maxlimit - fieldCtrl.value.length;

}
```

Comment: One more query..We had also used the same function earlier and used it on keyup and keydown of textbox(multiline) as follows:                  txtRemark.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "textCounter(this," + txtRemarksRem.ClientID + ", '2000')");

Comment: the difference here is that we were passing the clientID not as string..and in the function were not trying to find control but directly getting it as field.value.string.                               Why is the same scenario not working here where I passes the clientID as string and then searched for control in javascript function.If we could avoid changing the javascript function I will not have to make changes elsewhere in calls.please suggest and explain me the difference in the two cases.

Comment: In your first case where field.value, is running, you are passing this, and this always return the calling context, so in txtRemark.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "textCounter(this," + txtRemarksRem.ClientID + ", '2000')"), this representing txtRemark Control.

Comment: you can change function to this, it will handle both case :  
function textCounter(field, rem, maxlimit) {
    if(typeof(field) == 'string')
       field = document.getElementById(field);
    if(typeof(rem) == 'string')
       rem = document.getElementById(rem);

    if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    else
        rem.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;

}

Comment: it the id and class both are same, then it will work, but in your clientScript.RegisterStartupScript method, you are enclosing them in single quotation, so it is taking as string not an object.